# How to use TypeScript Declaration File with mocha tests?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, typescript-typings, ts-node

I have a TypeScript project, where the test are written in TypeScript. I want to use `mocha` to directly test TS files. I'm using ts-node for that, as described in [ts-node#mocha](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#mocha).
In the project I'm using a JS library which doesn't have TS type definitions. So I created a `d.ts` file for that. Everything works well when compiling and running the projects. However mocha fails with:

```
% yarn mocha --require ts-node/register --require source-map-support/register ./test/*.ts 

src/client.ts:3:26 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'algosdk'. '/home/robert/projects/algorand/ts-mocha/node_modules/algosdk/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/algosdk` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'algosdk';`

3 import * as algosdk from "algosdk";
```

It seams that ts-node doesn't recognize the `d.ts` files.

The only solution which works is to use `require` instead of `import` statement, but this will not link the types to algosdk.

#### How to use mocha with TS files and type definition file?

This is the project structure (also in [github](https://github.com/robert-zaremba/bootstrap-mocha-typescript)):

```
├── build    <-- JS from compiled TS go here
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── src
├── @types  <-- d.ts files 
├── test
├── tsconfig.json
```

The `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./build",

    "typeRoots" : ["./@types", "node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules"],
  "include": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "@types"
  ]
}
```

#### UPDATE

I confirm that the problem is related to `ts-node`, not to `mocha`. Running:

```
yarn ts-node src/client.ts
```

returns the same error.

#### References:

- [Mocha + ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#mocha)
- [TypeScript: Could not find a declaration file for module in unit tests, only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496973/typescript-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-in-unit-tests-only)

Comment: It seams that this is a problem of `ts-node`, not mocha. When running ts-node directly, it also can't find declaration files from custom locations. This is weird, because tsc works.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you can add the following configuration to `tsconfig.json` file.

```json
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
```

it works well on my side.

Comment: I get `Unknown compiler option 'ts-node'.`

Comment: The `ts-node` node must not be inside the `compiler-options`, it must be at the root of `ts-config.json`.

Comment: but what does it do? [DOKU](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/options#files)